# Is HttpContext usage in SpaPrerenderingExtensions Multiple Threads safe?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Below is the code from Microsoft's `SpaPrerenderingExtensions` used for Server Side Rendering for apps like Angular when using .net Core:

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
{
    [Obsolete("Prerendering is no longer supported out of box")]
    public static class SpaPrerenderingExtensions
    {
        [Obsolete("Prerendering is no longer supported out of box")]
        public static void UseSpaPrerendering(this ISpaBuilder spaBuilder, Action<SpaPrerenderingOptions> configuration)
        {
            if (spaBuilder == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("spaBuilder");
            }

            if (configuration == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("configuration");
            }

            SpaPrerenderingOptions options = new SpaPrerenderingOptions();
            configuration(options);
            string bootModulePath = options.BootModulePath;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bootModulePath))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("To use UseSpaPrerendering, you must set a nonempty value on the $BootModulePath property on the $SpaPrerenderingOptions.");
            }

            Task buildOnDemandTask = options.BootModuleBuilder?.Build(spaBuilder);
            IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder = spaBuilder.ApplicationBuilder;
            IServiceProvider applicationServices = applicationBuilder.ApplicationServices;
            INodeServices nodeServices = GetNodeServices(applicationServices);
            CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken = applicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHostApplicationLifetime>().ApplicationStopping;
            string applicationBasePath = applicationServices.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>().ContentRootPath;
            JavaScriptModuleExport moduleExport = new JavaScriptModuleExport(bootModulePath);
            PathString[] excludePathStrings = (options.ExcludeUrls ?? Array.Empty<string>()).Select((string url) => new PathString(url)).ToArray();
            TimeSpan buildTimeout = spaBuilder.Options.StartupTimeout;
            applicationBuilder.Use(async delegate (HttpContext context, Func<Task> next)
            {
                PathString[] array = excludePathStrings;
                foreach (PathString other in array)
                {
                    if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(other))
                    {
                        await next();
                        return;
                    }
                }

                if (buildOnDemandTask != null && !buildOnDemandTask.IsCompleted)
                {
                    await buildOnDemandTask.WithTimeout(buildTimeout, "The prerendering build process did not complete within the " + $"timeout period of {buildTimeout.Seconds} seconds. " + "Check the log output for error information.");
                }

                RemoveConditionalRequestHeaders(context.Request);
                string originalAcceptEncodingValue = GetAndRemoveAcceptEncodingHeader(context.Request);
                using MemoryStream outputBuffer = new MemoryStream();
                Stream originalResponseStream = context.Response.Body;
                context.Response.Body = outputBuffer;
                try
                {
                    await next();
                    outputBuffer.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                }
                finally
                {
                    context.Response.Body = originalResponseStream;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(originalAcceptEncodingValue))
                    {
                        context.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.AcceptEncoding] = originalAcceptEncodingValue;
                    }
                }

                if (!IsSuccessStatusCode(context.Response.StatusCode) || !IsHtmlContentType(context.Response.ContentType))
                {
                    await outputBuffer.CopyToAsync(context.Response.Body);
                }
                else
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> {
                    {
                        "originalHtml",
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outputBuffer.GetBuffer())
                    } };
                    options.SupplyData?.Invoke(context, dictionary);
                    var (requestAbsoluteUrl, requestPathAndQuery) = GetUnencodedUrlAndPathQuery(context);
                    await ServePrerenderResult(context, await Prerenderer.RenderToString(applicationBasePath, nodeServices, applicationStoppingToken, moduleExport, requestAbsoluteUrl, requestPathAndQuery, dictionary, 0, context.Request.PathBase.ToString()));
                }
            });
        }

        private static bool IsHtmlContentType(string contentType)
        {
            if (string.Equals(contentType, "text/html", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return contentType?.StartsWith("text/html;", StringComparison.Ordinal) ?? false;
        }

        private static bool IsSuccessStatusCode(int statusCode)
        {
            if (statusCode >= 200)
            {
                return statusCode < 300;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private static void RemoveConditionalRequestHeaders(HttpRequest request)
        {
            request.Headers.Remove(HeaderNames.IfMatch);
            request.Headers.Remove(HeaderNames.IfModifiedSince);
            request.Headers.Remove(HeaderNames.IfNoneMatch);
            request.Headers.Remove(HeaderNames.IfUnmodifiedSince);
            request.Headers.Remove(HeaderNames.IfRange);
        }

        private static string GetAndRemoveAcceptEncodingHeader(HttpRequest request)
        {
            IHeaderDictionary headers = request.Headers;
            string result = null;
            if (headers.ContainsKey(HeaderNames.AcceptEncoding))
            {
                result = (string?)headers[HeaderNames.AcceptEncoding];
                headers.Remove(HeaderNames.AcceptEncoding);
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static (string, string) GetUnencodedUrlAndPathQuery(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            string rawTarget = httpContext.Features.Get<IHttpRequestFeature>()!.RawTarget;
            HttpRequest request = httpContext.Request;
            return ($"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host}{rawTarget}", rawTarget);
        }

        private static async Task ServePrerenderResult(HttpContext context, RenderToStringResult renderResult)
        {
            context.Response.Clear();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(renderResult.RedirectUrl))
            {
                bool permanent = renderResult.StatusCode.GetValueOrDefault() == 301;
                context.Response.Redirect(renderResult.RedirectUrl, permanent);
                return;
            }

            if (renderResult.Globals != null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Globals is not supported when prerendering via UseSpaPrerendering(). Instead, your prerendering logic should return a complete HTML page, in which you embed any information you wish to return to the client.");
            }

            if (renderResult.StatusCode.HasValue)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = renderResult.StatusCode.Value;
            }

            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(renderResult.Html);
        }

        private static INodeServices GetNodeServices(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            INodeServices nodeServices = (INodeServices)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(INodeServices));
            return nodeServices ?? NodeServicesFactory.CreateNodeServices(new NodeServicesOptions(serviceProvider));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the example usage in Startup file

```
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            spa.UseSpaPrerendering(options =>
            {

            });

        });
```

UseSpaPrerendering method calls the `await Prerenderer.RenderToString(...)` and then pass the output (ssr rendered response eg. from Angular app) to `await ServePrerenderResult(context,...)`:

```
await ServePrerenderResult(context, await Prerenderer.RenderToString(applicationBasePath, nodeServices, applicationStoppingToken, moduleExport, requestAbsoluteUrl, requestPathAndQuery, dictionary, 0, context.Request.PathBase.ToString()));
```

My question is, is it thread safe to pass `HttpContext` to `ServePrerenderResult` and then perform operations like `context.Response.StatusCode` ?

Keeping this in mind that during SSR, apps like Angular may make http requests (async operation).

```
.net core > nodejs > angular app > http call to api

.net core < nodejs < angular app prepares html response using api data < response from api
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/best-practices?view=aspnetcore-7.0#do-not-store-ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-a-field

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/Services/SpaPrerenderingService.cs#L310) an example of how you can change the statuscode during SSR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, `HttpContext` may only be used by one thread at a time. It is perfectly safe to use with `async` methods that are immediately `await`ed.

The doc warning you linked to doesn't have anything to do with multithreaded access. It's warning users not to access the `HttpContext` in a constructor. At the time of construction, the context may or may not exist yet.

Comment: Thank you Stephen, just for the sake for further clarity, this is the same even if the awaited task takes longer, for example in case of ssr, it instiate node instance and execute angular app, which may make an http request await for its response, prepare html and return it to .net core app?

Comment: Yes; as long as it's awaited, the length doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen, really appreciate your help.